# add all count rows in multiple csv file and group by folder

Tags: python

I have a code ready which gets me the count of a file.
But I want to group my counts by folder.
E.g. I have 3 folders: USA, India and Germany.
USA contain sub folders like Virginia, Texas. So in Virginia there are 3 csv files and there total count is 15 rows and in Texas total count is 5 rows.
So Total count of rows by folder:

USA - 20
India - 400
Germany - 5440

**Code:**

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
files = glob.glob('Folder/*.csv')
d = {f: sum(1 for line in open(f)) for f in files}
print (pd.Series(d))
print (pd.Series(d).rename('rows').rename_axis('filename').reset_index())
```

Let me know how to do this